# GADM shapefile former countries

Tags: shapefile, maps, gadm

I am looking for country shapefiles of former countries (i.e. USSR, Sudan, Yugoslavia, Ethiopia, Czechoslovakia, Netherlands Antilles) - ideally WGS84. Does anyone know if GADM or any other website provides them?

Comment: https://icr.ethz.ch/data/cshapes/

Comment: If you are looking for open data then opendata.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask